# wrong count of files samba windows/linux

Tags: windows, samba4, smbfs, smbclient

i have a problem, i have a shared folder via samba, it works perfectly except if it has allot of files/folders, for example: one subfolder has 885 pdf's and browsing with linux i can see all of them, but in windows i only see 624 (and it depends on the windows version), i'm using the same user and both windows and linux using the same protocol version.

```
smbstatus -b
Samba version 4.13.13-Debian
PID     Username     Group        Machine                                   Protocol Version  Encryption           Signing              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
150556  miguel       domain users *.178 (ipv4:*.178:59056)  SMB3_11           -                    partial(AES-128-CMAC) <- debian 11 specifc folder 885 pdf's
150578  miguel       domain users *.113 (ipv4:*.113:62311)  SMB3_11           -                    partial(AES-128-CMAC) <- windows server 2016 specifc folder 624 (this varies betwin computer) pdf's
```

Comment: Can you give an example of files which are not visible by Windows? Something like `ls -la </path/to/file>`

Comment: For example, this one:

-rwxrwxrwx 1 nobody domain users 784453 fev 27  2018 'IEC 60990 (2015).pdf'